# Не могу установить pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5, модули

я пробовал (в cmd):

```
python -m pip install pyqt5
python -m pip install pyqt5-tools
```

output(in cmd):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QDcxUgSgwp-hwUnV7RgsPJSDLjA0f0rV

Answer (score 0):

Нет доступа к google диску. А какая у вас версия python установлена? Вы можете попробовать использовать easy_install вместо pip. Только в самых последних версиях python easy_install, как я помню, убрали.

Comment: python 3.10.2, also updated access to google drive(sorry because i didn’t do that earlier)